# React Native - how to go back to app from settings automatically?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am implementing the location tracking in background using React Native. The plan is to allow user to select 'Always', in Location, from Settings of the app. I did it by using:

- react-native-permission
- Linking (module in react native)

My question is:

- Can we move directly to the Location in Settings, instead of moving to Settings then select Location?
- After selecting 'Always'/'Always Allow' in iOS/Android, can we move back to the app automatically?

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For iOS the answers are no and no.

Comment: @Paulw11: Thank you for the quick reply, even the answer hurts me somehow, lol